# Derby db stating that column does not exist when it does

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

Ok so I have an application that connects to a database that has a customer table. In the customer table I capture a range of different values. VH_ID is a foreign key to the vehicle table and the insurance_ID is also a foreign key to the insurance table.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**Edit**

```
public CustomerInformation getCustomerInfo(String customerName) {
    CustomerInformation info = new CustomerInformation();
    ResultSet result;
    try {
        String sqlStatement = "SELECT "
                + DBStrings.C_NAME + ","
                + DBStrings.C_ADDRESS + ","
                + DBStrings.C_PHONENO + ","
                + DBStrings.C_EMAIL + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_ID + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_MODEL + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_YEAR + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_REGO + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_CHASSIS + ","
                + DBStrings.C_VH_VIN + ","
                + DBStrings.C_INSURANCE
                + " FROM " + DBStrings.CUSTOMER + " WHERE " + DBStrings.C_ID + " = " + this.getCustomerId(customerName);
        result = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
        while (result != null && result.next()) {
            info.setName(result.getString(DBStrings.C_NAME));
            info.setAddress(result.getString(DBStrings.C_ADDRESS));
            info.setPhoneNumber(result.getString(DBStrings.C_PHONENO));
            info.setEmail(result.getString(DBStrings.C_EMAIL));
            info.setRego(result.getString(DBStrings.C_VH_REGO) + "");
            info.setChassis(result.getString(DBStrings.C_VH_CHASSIS) + "");
            info.setVin(result.getString(DBStrings.C_VH_VIN) + "");
            info.setVehicleModel(result.getString(DBStrings.C_VH_MODEL) + "");
            info.setYear(result.getInt(DBStrings.C_VH_YEAR) + "");
            info.setInsurance(this.getInsuranceFromId(result.getInt(DBStrings.C_INSURANCE)));
            info.setVehicleMake(this.getVehicleFromId(result.getInt(DBStrings.C_VH_ID)));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Database.class
                .getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return info;
}
```

That is the new code with the ResultSet nested inside the method. Now I am getting the error:

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet not open. Operation 'getInt' not permitted. Verify that autocommit is OFF.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.ResultSet.getInt(Unknown Source)
at Database.Database.getCustomerInfo(Database.java:599)
```

Statement

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "user", "pass");
statement = connection.createStatement();
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain column named VH_MODEL does exist?

Comment: I am ABSOLUTELY positive. I am adding the customer information into that table with the exact same string used DBStrings.C_VH_MODEL. And when looking at the database in the services section in netbeans the data is there.. I am unsure why its not grabbing the data..

Comment: Did you try to run contents of String sqlStatement against database, not from the code? Does problem persist?

Comment: Works no problem doing it directing against the database. It seems very odd that it is not grabbing the data.

Comment: rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement); rs is not a local variable for this method. It can be possibly overwritten by other process. I suggest you make it local variable ResultSet rs = ...
Same for statement.

Comment: I have nested the ResultSet inside the method now as you can see from the edit above. I am not geting a new error. It is regards to the VH_ID (Foreign Key)

Comment: Please show the code initializing statement variable.

Comment: Just updated it above.

Comment: Try moving statement = connection.createStatement(); into this method as well. Who knows what happened to it before. 
You can also try to do connecion.setAutoCommit(false); as suggested by error statement.

Comment: I tried the Auto commit to false but that had no effect. Still gave the same error. I am not to sure why it is doing this. I have renamed all the database columns to have CUSTOMER_ infront of the columns now just incase there was something wrong with the naming and was clashing but that is not the case either.

Comment: Did you try moving statement = connection.createStatement(); into this method?

Comment: Yes get the same issue as above. Doesn't help at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the work around that I did to solve this issue was to create another method just specifically for retrieving the vehicle make. Seems a bit pointless but for the life of me I have no idea why it is not accepting it. The method has exactly the same contents for retrieving the data as in the first method.. Seems very odd.

```
    String sqlStatement = "SELECT "
            + DBStrings.C_VH_ID
            + " FROM " + DBStrings.CUSTOMER + " WHERE " + DBStrings.C_ID + " = " + customerId;
    rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlStatement);
    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
        int vh_id = rs.getInt(DBStrings.C_VH_ID);
        vehicle = this.getVehicleFromId(vh_id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have column VH_MODEL twice in your query due to a "copy-paste accident" in the constants, i.e. another constant also expands to "VH_MODEL", specifically one of the columns following VH_MODEL in the get sequence. The DBMS would rename the result columns to make them unique in this case I guess. This would explain the strange situation where `excuteQuery` works while the `getString` fails.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. Shifting the setVehicleMake down to the bottom it switches the error from being on VH_MODEL column to VH_ID column.

Comment: That would mean that C_VH_ID expands to "VH_MODEL" which you probably verified to not be the case. It was just a theory... Could you log the `sqlStatement` and add it to the question?